# clone img from one div to another, but only get 1 clone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What i want is to clone the image to various spots inside the frame, but i can get only one instead of many, can someone please say to me what i'm doing wrong, cause i cant see?? im doing kind of map of terrain, where i can fertilize the land, using clone images from one div to another ( frame div), any doubts about the functionality, can ask me.
PS: Im new to all of this stuff.

```
<div class="row">
            <table>
                <tbody>
                <?php 
                for($i = 0, $size = count($farm)-1; $i < $size; $i++) {
                    if($i == 0) 
                        echo '<tr>';

                    if($flag == 1){
                        echo '</tr>';
                        echo '<tr>';
                        $flag = 0;
                    }
                    if($farm[$i]['id_field'] == $farm[$i+1]['id_field']) {
                        echo '<td>';
                            echo '<div id="'.$farm[$i]['section_name'].'" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="width:60px; height:60px; border:1px solid #aaaaaa; 
                            background:#CCFF99"><center>'.$farm[$i]['section_name'].'</center></div>';
                        echo '</td>';
                    }else
                        $flag = 1;

                    if($i == $size - 1)
                        echo '</tr>';
                }?>
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <div class="drag">
                <img id="treatment" src="<?=base_url()?>/public/img/treat.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"  width="40" height="40" />
            </div>
        </div>

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //Counter
            counter = 0;
            //Make element draggable
            $(".drag").draggable({
                helper: 'clone',
                containment: 'frame',
                //When first dragged
                stop: function (ev, ui) {
                    var pos = $(ui.helper).offset();
                    objName = "#clonediv" + counter
                    $(objName).css({
                        "left": pos.left,
                        "top": pos.top
                    });
                    $(objName).removeClass("drag");
                    //When an existiung object is dragged
                    $(objName).draggable({
                        containment: 'parent',
                        stop: function (ev, ui) {
                            var pos = $(ui.helper).offset();
                            console.log($(this).attr("id"));
                            console.log(pos.left)
                            console.log(pos.top)
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            //Make element droppable
            $("#frame").droppable({
                drop: function (ev, ui) {
                    if (ui.helper.attr('id').search(/drag[0-9]/) != -1) {
                        counter++;
                        var element = $(ui.draggable).clone();
                        element.addClass("tempclass");
                        $(this).append(element);
                        $(".tempclass").attr("id", "clonediv" + counter);
                        $("#clonediv" + counter).removeClass("tempclass");
                        //Get the dynamically item id
                        draggedNumber = ui.helper.attr('id').search(/drag([0-9])/)
                        itemDragged = "dragged" + RegExp.$1
                        console.log(itemDragged)
                        $("#clonediv" + counter).addClass(itemDragged);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of doing like that you can do like this, i think you will get the same result.

view:
        
            function myFunction(elmnt,clr) {
                elmnt.style.backgroundColor = clr;
                document.getElementById("allValues").value += elmnt.id;
            }

this way you will get all the selected rows, instead of dragging and drop an image, you just paint the selected div, and increment to element, this ways when you submit, you will get all the divs selected.